# openstack ceiolometer is throwing unknown error while installing

Tags: python, swift, openstack

I have installed pre setting(setuptools, pbr and other rpm), and then I am running following cmd to install:

****sudo python setup.py install**

> > error in setup command: Error parsing /home/skumar/ceilometer/setup.cfg: OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory**

I can't get the problem.

My setup.cfg file is:
https://github.com/openstack/ceilometer/blob/stable/icehouse/setup.cfg

Comment: I think you need a) to format your command and error as "Code" and b) Show the rest of the error message!

Comment: Thanks Steve, I have fommatted it.It is the only error that is shown.

Comment: In my experience python errors are longer and give a trace back including things like the name of the missing file.  You also need to mention which exact versions of python, ceiolometer, etc. you are trying to use. BTW your title is misleading the error is known "No such file or directory"

Comment: What's this got to do with Swift?

Answer (score 1):

Ran into a similar problem trying to install a new python-neutronclient.  I didn't know anything about pbr, but apparently it uses it.  I found from [here](http://www.stephenwalker.com/2014/05/error-installing-python-module-that-uses-pbr/) that git needed to be installed.  Once I installed git and re-ran setup.py install, it gave me a different error:

```
error in setup command: Error parsing /tmp/python-neutronclient-contrail-icehouse/setup.cfg: Exception: Versioning for this project requires either an sdist tarball, or access to an upstream git repository. Are you sure that git is installed?
```

I removed the unzipped directory, checked it out via git, installed python-dev, and re-ran the setup.py install with success.